# Thread coordination with WaitForSingleObject and CEvent in MFC

Tags: mfc

In one of my MFC applications there are several worker threads. Nature of these threads are as below:

1. Most of the threads execute their tasks once and wait for a condition to be true for further execution.
2. In few cases thread waits infinitely until the condition becomes true and in other cases it waits for certain time periods and based on the condition becomes true or expiry of the time period whichever is earlier, it takes some action and again starts waiting.
3. Threads have to run throughout the life cycle of the application but not necessarily working every moment.

Currently each thread is having an infinite loop, where it executes it's task; as each thread has to work throughout the application's life cycle, I don't want to close these threads every time and recreate. Inside the loop I have used WaitForSingleObject with an auto-reset CEvent for such thread coordination. CEvent objects are signaled from any thread or from UI thread.

In this context I have following queries:

i. Is the approach well justified for my requirement?

ii. Is there any significant overhead of using so many CEvent objects for the purpose.
Is there any better alternative?

iii. In some cases a thread waits infinitely for a CEvent object to be signalled and the object is only signalled from windows message handler after it receives a Message from another thread.The message is received through PostMessage. Here I'm concerned about loosing a message sent from a thread. If Message handler skips a message, it cannot state of the CEvent object and the waiting thread has to wait infinitely. What precautions have to be taken to avoid such situation ? Is there any better way to reconstruct the scheme ?

Please suggest me some better alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Don't worry about multiple CEvent objects. In your case you must have at least one event per thread.

I am not sure what method you use to exit the thread. But you may need additional CEvent object to detect whether you have to exit the thread gracefully.

So in this case you would use WaitForMultipleObjects in each thread (1 event would be to run or not, another event would be to exit the thread or not).

If there are too many threads, that I would suggest that you spawn child threads when ever required. The child thread would simply run once and exit. In the parent thread you would again wait to see which child thread must be run. You can detect which thread to spawn based on array of event objects. This approach will take up less system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Use WaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject. The first event in each event array should be a global CEvent that is set to shutdown the app. Each thread detects this event and exits cleanly by returning from the thread function.

After setting the shutdown event (typically in OnClose) use WaitForMultipleObjects on the thread handles to wait for all the secondary threads to close. This makes sure that any global data that the threads may be accessing remains allocated until the threads are gone.

Comment: I think your answer explains only about how to close the application in clean way. The main thread can ensure that all worker threads have been successfully exited; therefore it's the time to deallocate all global resources and Quit. I'm doing it in different way using a boolean variable but this doesn't ensure proper closure of the worker threads before deallocation of global data used by those threads. Although it's very much clear how to implement;could you please give some code snippets which implement the idea? Do you have any suggestion on my queries in my post ?

Answer (score 0):

In my application I'm using 10 to 12 worker threads only. I read somewhere that 
when a thread calls a wait function, it enters into kernel mode from the user mode. It is bit costly because to enter the kernel mode, approximately 1000 processor cycles are required which may be too expensive in a concrete situation.

However, as goths and ScottMcP suggested, I'm using WaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject in the following way to ensure graceful thread closure before cleaning up any resources used by the thread.

```
CEvent doWork,exitThread; //Auto reset events
CWinThread* MyThread;
UINT MyThreadFunction(LPVOID param);

BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    //Other initialization code
    MyThread=AfxBeginThread(MyThreadFunction, CMyDlg::GetSafeHwnd());
    //Any other initialization code
    return TRUE;
}

UINT MyThreadFunction(LPVOID param) 
{
HANDLE waitEvents[2];
waitEvents[0]=doWork;
waitEvents[1]=exitThread;
while(true)
{

  DWORD stat=::WaitForMultipleObjects(2, waitEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);
  switch(stat)
  {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0:
        // doWork CEvent is signalled; proceed to do some work
    break;

    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        //exitThread is signalled; so exit from this thread handler function
    return 0;

    case WAIT_FAILED:
        // failure may be related to wrong handles passed for lpHandles 
    break;

    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        // not applicable here because dwMilliseconds parameter is set to INFINITE
    break;
  }
}
return 0;
}

CMyDlg::OnClose()
{
  exitThread.SetEvent();
  DWORD Stat=WaitForSingleObject(MyThread->m_hThread, INFINITE);   
  if(Stat==WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    //Thread supposed to be Exited
    //Cleanup allocated resources here
  }
  else if(Stat==WAIT_TIMEOUT)
  {
    //not applicable here
  }
  else if(Stat==WAIT_FAILED)
  {
    //Invalid thred handle passed or something else
  }
  EndDialog(0);
}
```

Please, do comment on my answer if anything wrong is detected or there is any scope of improvement.